# Пропадает OpenGL контент при вытаскивании панели за пределы RadDocking

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, telerik, opentk

Есть компонент WinForms сделанный на основе OpenTK.GLControl. В нём выводится диаграмма:

[image: Нормально нарисованная диаграмма]

Этот компонент используется в проекте WPF, для него сделана такая разметка:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ProductionPlan.View.DiagramControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WorkLoad="clr-namespace:WorkLoad;assembly=WorkLoad"
    xmlns:WorkPlan="clr-namespace:WorkPlan;assembly=WorkPlan"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    d:DesignHeight="600"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="План">
            <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="WorkPlanWFHost">
                <WorkPlan:WorkPlan x:Name="WorkPlan" />
            </WindowsFormsHost>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`UserControl` в свою очередь лежит в `RadDocumentPane`, которая добавляется в коллекцию открытых панелей здесь:

```
    <telerik:RadDocking Grid.Row="1" PanesSource="{Binding OpenedPanes}">
        <telerik:RadDocking.DockingPanesFactory>
            <telerik:DockingPanesFactory />
        </telerik:RadDocking.DockingPanesFactory>
```

Пока панель лежит в контейнере `RadDocking` - диаграмма нормально рисуется, реагирует на управление мышкой - всё в порядке. Но стоит вытащить панель с диаграммой за пределы `RadDocking` - диаграмма пропадает и панель выглядит вот так:

[image: Диаграмма пропала]

В методе отрисовки диаграммы в OpenTK собираю ошибки OpenGL - но их нет, всё чисто.

Есть идеи, как можно исправить отрисовку OpenGL на вытащенной из `RadDocking` панели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ от 2010 года на сайте [Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/forums/wpf-frame-control-not-visible-in-floating-window).

> When a pane goes floating, actually it is placed in a chromeless window. Unfortunately, placing a WindowsFormsHost in a chromeless window is not supported scenario in WPF. If you debug it, you will see that the host is still there, but it is not visible. This is a limitation of the RadDocking at this stage.

Так что это ограничение до сих пор не исправлено и надо искать другие способы для рисования с помощью OpenGL. Буду рассмотреть на SharpGL.WPF.